# Is it possible to use an older Canon Scanner with OS 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: macos, compatibility, scanning, canon

My Canon LIDE 600F scanner is old but still worked very well. When I upgraded to OS 10.11 my computer no longer recognized the scanner. Canon has officially stated that they are not making new drivers for this product, but I had a similar issue with my tablet not working and was able to find a solution on this site. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: VueScan might help.  Honestly, you're better off buying a new AIO then trying to get these older machines working.  You can also try deleting anything related to this Canon scanner that's on your Mac then checking if Preview will recognize it.  I was reading [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7276906?start=0&tstart=0) that some people had a limited amount of success doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I tried both Vuescan and Preview and they didn't work. I guess it's time to buy a new one.

Comment: I'm sorry those didn't work.  To help others who might have the same scanner, I'll add my comment to the answer for you to accept.  Then you can add your comments to the answer.  Other people in similar circumstances will know it's better to buy a new one.

Comment: Vue Scan gives you a 'free' trial that puts water marks all over your scan - too much to view image! buying their lite version is supposed to unlock it - but I couldn't find any feedback that it worked - only complaints that the 'code' didn't unlock the software.
I'm also trying a supposed update of scangear - installs twice - but not appearing on computer. Bought an Epson out of disgust .... but still want my lovely 600F lide back!

Comment: Try with the macOS TWAIN Sane drivers - http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/ - they aim to support a lot of old TWAIN devices like yours. See instructions here - https://macmanus.nl/2015/11/10/fixed-use-unsupported-scanner-in-osx-10-11-el_capitan/

Comment: Another option is using VMWare, Parallels or VirtualBox and loading up the last version of OS X that runs your drivers. Not recommended unless you already use virtualisation software.

Answer (score 1):

**VueScan** might help. Honestly, you're better off buying a new AIO then trying to get these older machines working. You can also try deleting anything related to this Canon scanner that's on your Mac then checking if Preview will recognize it. I was reading [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7276906?start=0&tstart=0) that some people had a limited amount of success doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ScanVue on Mac OS X, both the 32 and 64 bit versions with no problems.  As far as the LiDE 600F (my scanner) is concerned, there is no 32 bit support on Mac OS anymore.  And the ScanVue developer cannot get access to the 64 bit drivers for this device (if they even exist).  It was always a good scanner and I would like to keep using it.  Unfortunately it is not possible unless Canon releases the drivers code and someone converts it to 64 bit.  Just a paperweight now. :(